# jQuery OwlCarousel v1.3.3 - center align items

Tags: javascript, css, owl-carousel

I have 4 items in a row in carousel sample. There is still about 50% empty unused space. 
**I want to align this items to the center.**

[image]

I tried to center them via `margin: 0 auto;` and `display: flex; align-items: center;` but with no success.

I found that `style="width: 2888px; left: 0px;"` is computed bis javascript owl.carousel.custom.js. Changing left to some value will work but is not what I expected.

Here are the computed values of the class `owl-wrapper-outer`:

[image]
How should I fix this in order to align items to the center?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found one solution, by directly changing javascript:

```
base.$owlWrapper.css({
    "left": (carouselWidth / 2) - ((base.itemWidth * base.$owlItems.length) / 2)
});
```